# Configure VSCode quick navigate to also list files in a node module dir?

Tags: visual-studio-code

On Mac, I use CMD+P to fuzzy search/jump to files.
By default it does not list files in node_modules.
I would like to make an exception and also list files in

`node_modules/<vendor>/<package>`

Is it doable? I identified the CMD+P shortcut as

`workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNextInFilePicker`

But I cant see any configuration options when searching for that key in the settings.

Comment: Look at the `Search: Exclude` setting.  Remove node-modules from it.

Comment: Yes but I do want to exclude the rest of that black hole and only allow a certain package